# In Chrome V8 Engine Source, What it means for?

Tags: c++, v8

I have a question in following piece of code.

```
#define V8_DECLARE_ONCE(NAME) ::v8::base::OnceType NAME
```

In cpp file, '::' means for referencing namespace, but where '::v8' included?

```
std::cout << ... << std::endl;
```

cout is under the 'std' namespace,,, but, in this case, i have no idea how to interpret it.

part of this code is following one.

```
 namespace v8 {
 namespace base {

 typedef AtomicWord OnceType;

 #define V8_ONCE_INIT 0

 #define V8_DECLARE_ONCE(NAME) ::v8::base::OnceType NAME
```

Comment: `::v8` means "get me `v8` from the top-level namespace"

Answer (score 1):

`::ns` means to look in the root namespace for `ns`. It's to avoid possible namespace collisions, since it avoids looking in the current namespace, if you define your own namespace and it has the same name. Here's an example that demonstrates the difference.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace v8 {

constexpr int val = 5;

} // namespace v8

namespace my {
namespace v8 {

constexpr int val = 10;

} // namespace my::v8

void some_func()
{
  std::cout << ::v8::val << ", " << v8::val << '\n';
}

} // namespace my

int main()
{
  my::some_func();
}
```

prints `5, 10`.

Comment: Great!! I got it ! Thx :)